# shell script to get key value

Tags: bash, shell

I have content like

```
key1="value1" key2="value2"
key1="value11" key2="value22"
key1="value111" key2="value222"
```

I want to output like

```
value1
value11
value111
```

i.e basically values for key one

but when I `grep` the entire line will be shown, I tried using `cut` still could not get expected result, can some help me to write scrip for this please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk you can search for given key like this:

```
awk -v s="key1" -F '[= "]+' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) if ($i==s) print $(i+1)}' file
value1
value11
value111

awk -v s="key2" -F '[= "]+' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) if ($i==s) print $(i+1)}' file
value2
value22
value222
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut` itself:

```
cut -d \" -f 2 < File
```

Set `"` as delimiter and extract the `2nd` field. Hope it helps.

Another similar solution with `awk`:

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}' File
```

Comment: This will work only if values are in 2nd field. e.g to print values of `key2` this answer needs to change.

Comment: From the question, "i.e basically values for key one" he was asking for "key1" values specifically. Hence...

Answer (score 1):

Using [`grep -P`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=grep):

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=key1=")[^"]*' file
value1
value11
value111
```